# Mui conditional rendering of one component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, conditional-rendering

I would like to set disableGutters for MUI Container when xs size.

So far I was only able to do it like so:

```
<Container disableGutters sx={{ display: { xs: 'block', md: 'none' } }}>
    ...lot of code
</Container>

<Container sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', md: 'block' } }}>
    ...lot of duplicit code
</Container>
```

But because there is a lot of duplicit code I don't feel good about this solution, so is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use the MUI breakpoints like this:

In your component you should add:

```
import { useMediaQuery, useTheme } from "@mui/material";
```

inside de component:

```
const theme = useTheme();
const isExtraSmallSize =  useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("xs"));
```

and then:

```
<Container disableGutters={isExtraSmallSize ? true : false} sx={{ display: { xs: 'block', md: 'none' } }}>
    ...lot of code
</Container>
```

or what you can do is use `isExtraSmallSize` to create the conditional rendering you need

A custom hook with `theme` and `useMediaQuery` is very useful, I recommend you to do it